# What of the probability of drawing a blue ball in this example?

Tags: probability

Given a box which contains $3$ red balls and $7$ blue balls. A ball is drawn from the box and a ball of the other color is then put into the box. A second ball is drawn from the box, What is the probability that the second ball is blue?

could anyone provide me any hint?

Please, don't offer a complete sketch of the solution, a hint is enough for me as this is a homework problem.

Comment: Draw a probability tree that considers all possible cases ending with the second ball being blue.

Comment: Is the first ball put back?

Comment: @Henry, No, it's replaced by a ball of the other color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the [Law of total probability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability), there is an obvious partition of events in this problem which you should use

EDIT: You can see from the picture that the probability tree uses the same formula $\mathbb{P}\left( A \right) = \mathbb{P}\left( {A|B} \right)\mathbb{P}\left( B \right) + \mathbb{P}\left( {A|{B^C}} \right)\mathbb{P}\left( {{B^C}} \right)$

[image: Probability tree]

Comment: We didn't take this law in class so I doubt if it's allowed to use it.

Comment: You should derive it yourself then, it is a simple matter. First, you write $\mathbb{P}\left( A \right) = \mathbb{P}\left( {A \cap \left( {B \cup {B^C}} \right)} \right)$, since $A = A \cap \left( {B \cup {B^C}} \right)$. Then, distributivity gives you $A \cap \left( {B \cup {B^C}} \right) = \left( {A \cap B} \right) \cup \left( {A \cap {B^C}} \right)$. Since $\mathbb{P}\left( {C \cup D} \right) = \mathbb{P}\left( C \right) + \mathbb{P}\left( D \right)$ when $C \cap D = \emptyset $, you get

Comment: $\mathbb{P}\left( A \right) = \mathbb{P}\left( {A \cap B} \right) + \mathbb{P}\left( {A \cap {B^C}} \right)$. Now, from the definition of conditional probability, $\mathbb{P}\left( {A \cap B} \right) = \mathbb{P}\left( {A|B} \right)\mathbb{P}\left( B \right)$, so $\mathbb{P}\left( A \right) = \mathbb{P}\left( {A|B} \right)\mathbb{P}\left( B \right) + \mathbb{P}\left( {A|{B^C}} \right)\mathbb{P}\left( {{B^C}} \right)$.

Comment: If you look at the other answers, you'll see that it's impossible to solve the problem without it

Comment: hmmm, I think that using probability trees is much more easier as Vizuna refered to, thanx for the explnation :)

Comment: The reason the probability tree works is exactly the formula above, it is just a graphical description of that formula. I'll add a picture

Comment: There, I hope it's clear now that using the probability tree is unjustified without knowing the law of total probability.

Answer (score 1):

$$P\left\{ \text{second blue}\right\} =$$$$P\left\{ \text{second blue}\mid\text{first blue}\right\} P\left\{ \text{first blue}\right\} +P\left\{ \text{second blue}\mid\text{first red}\right\} P\left\{ \text{first red}\right\} $$